# Set image as Data in notification extension

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have function that receives image as DATA

I can convert it to:

```
let uiImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: thumb)!
```

But how do I set it to UNNotificationAttachment? It expects url...

```
let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment(identifier : "image", url: fileUrl, options: nil)
content.attachment = [attachment]
```

Comment: Write your thumb to a directory in your app Bundle. Where to save it depends if you want to keep it for later use or not and also if it should be visible to the user or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the image to the filesystem, for example to `.cachesDirectory`, and create UNNotificationAttachment using the file URL.